# Rails, how to remove a directory from eager load paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, rails-engines

I see lots of instructions on how to add a directory to Rails eager load paths and auto load paths, but none on how to remove a directory.

Here's my problem. I've inherited a project with extremely convoluted code and have to make some changes. They've created lots of rails engines, to be used in different versions of the app. In one version controllers and views from an engine are overridden in the main app by creating controllers and views with the same directory structure and names as in the engine. They then get loaded ahead of the controllers and views in the engine.

The engines are so tightly coupled to the apps and to each other that it's impossible to test the engines in isolation. Which means that to test the code inside the engine you have to run in the context of the main app. But the main app loads its own versions of the controllers and views before the versions from the engines. So I can't test the code in the controllers and views. But....

I'm guessing that there might be a way to remove the eagerload/autoload paths in the main app that loads the override controllers and views, so that the controllers and views in the engine can be loaded.

How do I remove a path from the list of eagerload/autoload paths?

Comment: Sounds complicated. I wonder why you would boot up one or more dummy apps?

Comment: I worked around this by unloading constants, pointing `require_relative etc` to the path I wanted and reloading constants. It's an old project with lots of insane code, so the answer to 'why would you want to do X' is 'because I'm forced to do stupid things just to get the effing thing working'

Comment: Sometimes that is a reasonable answer